# Issues With JMeter Proxy Recording

Tags: java, jmeter

I am having some issues with JMeter recording proxy issues.

I am a Java Developer. I am performing load testing for an
application using JMeter.

I have developed one application in JSP with Struts which contains two 
pages.

The First page contains Login Page which contains fields like username & 
password with Submit button.

On entering the URL in IE8.0 i.e. as login.jsp , this action is recording by jmeter correctly.After entering username & password and clicking the submit button it landed at the second page, but  this event is not recorded by JMeter proxy server. But when I click on Logout Link at Second page, that event that is clicking the logout link is recording properly.

The major problem which I am facing is when I perform any action on buttons JMeter is not performing recording but when I am clicking any link that action has been recorded by the JMeter properly. Please help me on this.

Do I need to add any thing for Submit button recording?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the proxy in your browser settings.

One good way you can try if this works, set the proxy settings, turn off the JMeter Proxy, and try to load your page. This should not work. Then turn the JMeter Proxy on, and reload your page. It should load and your Recording Controller should capture the requests.

This worked best for me in Firefox, IE did somehow not use the JMeter Proxy even if I set it. I did not look further into that, as with Firefox it worked fine.

Here is a step-by-step instruction on running the proxy: [Link](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: I  have followed all the steps in PDF. but still it's not working. Submit button we have to write any script? Does we requried to add anything on jsp page to record?

Comment: Its recording only the pages which we are having href links or hit on the URL.If we have buttons like Submit, its not recording the page but navigation is happening for second page. Please help me on this. My work has been stopped.

Comment: What have you set in the JMeter Proxy under URL patterns to include? This determines which page requests are recorded by the proxy. If you have jsp pages this needs to be .*\.jsp, you could even try .* and see what happens...

Comment: Hi, Its working fine. I have given .* in URL Pattern. Thanks for the help.